# Using While with SELECT statemtent

Tags: sql-server

My goal is to create a number of columns with empty cells.

Basically this just with a defined number of columns:

```
SELECT NOM_EMP,PRENOM_EMP, '' as [1], '' as [2] 
FROM EMPLOYE
```

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
DECLARE @I AS INT

SET @I = 10

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NOM_EMP)  as 'Number', NOM_EMP, Prenom_EMP, 
    WHILE @I < 10
    BEGIN
         SELECT '' AS
    END 
FROM EMPLOYE
```

Is that possible to achieve?

Expected results: (assuming that I used 8 in the loop)

[image]

Comment: Your pseudo-code isn't clear. Add the expected results to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is declarative by design, and does not support macro substitution.

This leaves Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @Int int = 8

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select NOM_EMP,PRENOM_EMP,'
+ (Select Stuff((Select ',[' +cast(N as varchar(25))+']=''''' 
                From (Select Top (@Int) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1) A
                For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
   )
+ ' From Employee'

Exec(@SQL)
```

**The Generated SQL**

```
Select NOM_EMP,PRENOM_EMP,[1]='',[2]='',[3]='',[4]='',[5]='',[6]='',[7]='',[8]='' 
 From Employee
```

Comment: It worked, I appreciate it. Can I put this in a stored procedure or function to call it?

Comment: @Zkai Happy to help.   Only in a stored procedue.   Functions do not accept dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use dynamic SQL, building the columns list with `XML PATH`:

```
DECLARE
      @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    , @i int = 10;

WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1000 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS i FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT NOM_EMP,PRENOM_EMP,' + 
    STUFF((SELECT ','''' AS ' + QUOTENAME(CAST(i AS nvarchar(4)))
    FROM t1000
    WHERE i < @i
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    + N' from EMPLOYE';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

In SQL Server 2017 and later, you could use substitute [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer.  You beat me by almost a minute.